# Deploy next js app to aws ec2 through codedeploy

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, next.js, aws-code-deploy

I created a new NextJS app, no changes just the basic boilerplate files, code, and folders. and pushed it to a CodeCommit repo. Already had a working CodePipeline and just swapped Source stages. Deployments are failing on Step 3, where a replacement instance is created, and Target Group shows the original instance is healthy but new instances are given a 403 error code.

For the appspec.yml file, I've set the source to `/` b/c that's what the [Next JS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction) said. I also tried setting it to `pages/_app.js` and `/app.js` b/c that's what [Fireship](https://youtu.be/Sklc_fQBmcs?t=238) mentioned as the entry. None have worked and codedeploy keeps failing. I talked to AWS Support and we narrowed it to Next JS causing the issue.

If you're also running a NextJS app and deploying it to EC2 through CodeDeploy and CodePipeline, what did you set the source path to? For both the appspec and Target Group health check. Do I need to use Docker and Kubernetes like this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53079815/how-to-deploy-next-js-on-aws-ec2-linux-instance)? Or are the failures caused by something else I should check?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using EC2 and CodeDeploy, follow [this AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/deploy-nextjs-app.html) and use Amplify to build and deploy your NextJS app. This is the link for using a custom domain: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-amazon-route-53.html